# MessageToMessageCodec vs MessageToMessageDecoder and MessageToMessageEncoder in netty

Tags: java, networking, netty, codec

I'm creating a packet based server application and I wanna know is it better to use a MessageToMessageCodec for both encoding and decoding packets or separate encoder and decoder for which one?

is there something specific that I need to consider for `MessageToMessageCodec`? why can't a `MessageToMessageCodec` be annotated as `@Sharable`?

the pipeline for each channel is something like this:

- LengthFieldPrepender
- LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder
- CryptoHandler (extends MessageToMessageCodec *used for both decrypting and
  encrypting packets*)
- PacketDecoder (extends MessageToMessageDecoder)
- PacketEncoder (extends MessageToMessageEncoder)
- NetworkHandler (extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler)

Should I use a `MessageToMessageCodec` for both encoding and decoding? what are the pros and cons and which one is more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the source, the codec just combines the encoder and decoder. It uses an instance of each under the covers: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/00afb19d7a37de21b35ce4f6cb3fa7f74809f2ab/codec/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/ByteToMessageCodec.java#L37-L39

There appears to be no difference between using the codec or using the encoder and decoder. Providing all 3 classes does allow the flexibility of one or the other if the solution requires for that and the convenience of the codec if not.

As an example, the `ByteToMessageCodec` can't be annotated as @Sharable because the `ByteToMessageDecoder` can't be annotated as @Sharable and the former is composed of the latter among other things.

The `ByteToMessageCodec` ultimately implements both `ChannelInboundHandler` and `ChannelOutboundHandler` so yes, you would use it for both encoding and decoding.